# Where to pass temp array when using recursive function?

Tags: php, recursion

I'm using a `foreach` loop inside my recursive function. But I have trouble figuring out where to pass my return statement. I need to return my temp array at some point, but I'm not sure how to do this:

```
<?php
    $patterns = function($array, $temp = array(), $i = 0, $id = 0, $parent = 0) use(&$patterns) {
        $return = null;

        if(array_key_exists($i, $array)) {
            foreach($array[$i] as $set) {
                if($parent == $set['id']) {
                    $data = array(
                        'id' => $set['id'],
                        'parent' => $set['parent']
                    );

                    array_push($temp, $data);
                }

                $patterns($array, $temp, $i + 1, $set['id'], $set['parent']);
            }
        }
    };

    print_r($patterns($rev_relations));
?>
```

This is my data:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
            [0] => Array(
                    [id] => 60
                    [parent] => 55
                )
            [1] => Array(
                    [id] => 57
                    [parent] => 54
                )
        )
    [1] => Array(
            [0] => Array(
                    [id] => 61
                    [parent] => 50
                )
            [1] => Array(
                    [id] => 54
                    [parent] => 49
                )
        )
    [2] => Array(
            [0] => Array(
                    [id] => 49
                    [parent] => 0
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: can you initilize an example input or similar so we can actually run the code?

Comment: In recursive functions all the input must come from the parameters and all the output must come as the return value. No other options should be considered.

Comment: zerkms, you're correct. I think I have encapsulated everything that I need in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php


//pass $temp by reference so outside variable gets populated
    $patterns = function($array, &$temp, $i = 0, $id = 0, $parent = 0) use(&$patterns) {
        $return = null;

        if(array_key_exists($i, $array)) {
            foreach($array[$i] as $set) {
                if($parent == $set['id']) {
                    $data = array(
                        'id' => $set['id'],
                        'parent' => $set['parent']
                    );

                    array_push($temp, $data);
                }

                $patterns($array, $temp, $i + 1, $set['id'], $set['parent']);
            }
        }
    };

    //actuall array is created on temp  here
    $temp=array();
    $patterns($rev_relations,$temp);
?>
```

wont this work? Never really worked with nameless functions, but this is how i would go about it on a normall recursive function

Ok, take two

```
<?php

    $patterns = function($array, $temp = array(), $i = 0, $id = 0, $parent = 0) use(&$patterns) {
        $return = null;

        if(array_key_exists($i, $array)) {
            foreach($array[$i] as $set) {


          if($parent == $set['id']) {
                $data = array(
                    'id' => $set['id'],
                    'parent' => $set['parent']
                );

                array_push($temp, $data);
            }

            return $patterns($array, $temp, $i + 1, $set['id'], $set['parent']);
        }
    }
    else
    {
       return $temp;
    }
};


$patterns($rev_relations);
?>
```

Comment: it wont return something, but populate the temp. otherwise you need an if that knows where it ends

Comment: For later purposes I need to keep data within the loop.

Comment: It is stadard procedure for a recursive function.if that calls itself with return.else that just returns

Comment: mistake again, it doesn't return. I mean, it does. But empty array.

Comment: Try var_dump($temp) at the else part. Is this what you need returned;

Comment: ok, the temp array is never updated after the array_push. Idea why?

Comment: must be logic error thanks for your help. ill accept answer as it seems like there's my logic error there.